# How do I encode a highly nested php array/object into JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

Note: this seems quite long, here's a short explanation for the people who don't want to (or don't need to) see all of my long explanation down below. I'm sorry if I put too much stuff here, but I thought it's better to give too much info rather than too little.

In short, I have an JS array full of objects. These objects have arrays as some of their properties. These arrays are of objects, which have arrays inside, which have objects inside. All in all, there are 5 levels of nesting. JavaScript's JSON.parse/stringify works fine on these, but when started making this program work across the server, I used JavaScript's JSON.stringify to send some data up and php's json_decode to read it. The php fiddles with the data, using it to edit the large object (stored in JSON format in txt file on server). Small functions like addMessage and createRoom do work but when I try to send up a 3-level object it doesn't work. I think the problem might be something to with trying to upload a stringified object, as my other php scripts receive parameters and then create the objects as stdClass from those.

Long boring version:

This question seems to be asked in variants in other places, but I can't find an answer that works for me. Basically, I am developing a online interactive whiteboard program. It uses JS as the main language and PHP to do all of the file-writing work. I store my data in a .txt file using json_encode. To read data from the file, my JS calls my php which decodes the file, gets the relevant data, encodes that, and echoes that. All of the data is made by the JS, and is oriented towards being edited by JS - all of it is constructed from JS Classes. Up until now my program has been working fine, with joining/creating whiteboards and a chat feature being relatively simple. When I tried to implement the whiteboard syncing across computers, I found that when I sent the new whiteboard data up to the php, and tried to put it in the file, json_encode failed. I'm getting this error from the Apache log: `PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`.
Instead of stopping the program, it goes on and corrupts the data file (probably need to put in some checks there) and kills the whole program.
This is how my data structures work (in JS, as it would be if I hard-coded it):

```
[ /* list of room objects */
    { /* a room object */
        name: 'example', 
        id: 'numbers', 
        whiteboardData: [
            { /* a shape object */
            color: [r, g, b],
            pointList: [
                { /* a vector object*/
                    x: 100,
                    y: 100,
                }
                /* heaps of other vector objects */
            ]
            }
        ], /* end of whiteboardData */
        chatMessages: [
            { /* a message object */
                sender: 'username',
                content: 'hi'
            }
            /* heaps of other message objects */
        ]
    }
    /* heaps of other room objects */
]
```

As I've said, it worked fine with the 3-level nesting of the messages, but the 5-level nesting of the point coordinates is not working. I can't simplify the program's data storage without rewriting most of it.
My php in pseudocode (because the code is a bit difficult to understand without reading my documentation):

```
receive id of the room that the whiteboard belongs to
receive whiteboard data as object
receive username of who made the edit (not used yet)

get contents of data file on server
do checks

decode data file and turn into object (roomData)
get the room as an object (actually a link to the room object in roomData)

decode the data that got sent up and turn into object
swap out the whiteboardData of the room object with the new data made in the line above

turn the main object (roomData) into a string (this is the one that keeps failing)
put the resulting string into the file
```

My php:

```
<?php
const roomDataFileUrl = "../!roomdata.txt";

$roomId = $_POST["roomId"];
$whiteboardDataStr = $_POST["whiteboardData"];
$editMadeBy = $_POST["editMadeBy"]; // unused as of now, may be used later on

// read data from file
$roomDataStr = file_get_contents(roomDataFileUrl);

if (strlen($roomDataStr) <= 0) {
    echo "||nonExistentRoom";
}

// do check for null
if ($roomDataStr !== null) {
    // if data file is empty, then just make empty array for data instead of reading file
    if (strlen($roomDataStr) <= 0) {
        $roomData = [];
    }
    else { // otherwise parse data
        $roomData = json_decode($roomDataStr);
    }

    $room = getRoom($roomData, $roomId);

    // check if room exists
    if ($room !== null) {
        // parse the whiteboard data and then put it in the room
        // this will kill the program is there's a problem with the whiteboard data, so no checks needed
        $whiteboardData = json_decode($whiteboardDataStr);
        $room->whiteboardData = $whiteboardData;



        // THIS LINE IS THE ONE THAT KEEPS FAILING
        $roomDataStr = json_encode($roomData);



        // put in file
        if (strlen($roomDataStr) > 0) {
            file_put_contents(roomDataFileUrl, $roomData);
        }
        else {
            echo "**unknownServerError";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "||nonExistentRoom";
    }
}
else {
    echo "**roomFileEmpty";
}

function getRoom($roomData, $roomId) {
    $room = null;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($roomData); $i ++) {
        $currentRoom = $roomData[$i];
        if ($currentRoom->id === $roomId) {
            $room = $currentRoom;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $room;
}

?>
```

My JS (two methods from a class clipped and edited because most of it is not needed)

```
drawWhiteboardData(serverResponse) {
  // I've removed about 20 lines of error processing here
  var whiteboardDataStr = response;
  var whiteboardData = JSON.parse(whiteboardDataStr);
  this.whiteboardPtr.shapeList = whiteboardData;
}

sendWhiteboardData() {
  var localWhiteboardData = this.whiteboardPtr.shapeList;
  // this stringify works fine - I've checked the output manually
  var localWhiteboardDataStr = JSON.stringify(localWhiteboardData);

  // serverCommsManager.sendWhiteboardData just turns the data into a post request and sends it to my php file using the keys that can be seen at the top of the php file
  this.serverCommsManagerPtr.sendWhiteboardData(
    localWhiteboardDataStr, this.successfulEditProtocol.bind(this));
  this.lastWhiteboardUpload = localWhiteboardDataStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way too much noise there for me to be able to easily see where the problem lies.

Rather than try to reason that out, I'll just present you with a solution that receives the data as if you'd hardcoded it, adds a new element to the `whiteboardData` array, before returning it. I'd expected to use fetch instead of the old XMLHttpRequest, but am a little rusty. This was easier for me.

### HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

var jsonObj = 
[ /* list of room objects */
    { /* a room object */
        name: 'example', 
        id: 'numbers', 
        whiteboardData: [
            { /* a shape object */
            color: [100, 150, 100],
            pointList: [
                { /* a vector object*/
                    x: 100,
                    y: 100,
                }
                /* heaps of other vector objects */
            ]
            }
        ], /* end of whiteboardData */
        chatMessages: [
            { /* a message object */
                sender: 'username',
                content: 'hi'
            }
            /* heaps of other message objects */
        ]
    }
    /* heaps of other room objects */
];

function ajaxPostFormData(url, formData, onSuccess, onError)
{
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onload = function(){onSuccess(this);}
    ajax.onerror = function(){onError(this);}
    ajax.open("POST",url,true);
    ajax.send(formData);
}

function onLoaded(evt)
{
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('whiteboardData', JSON.stringify(jsonObj) );
    ajaxPostFormData('blahBlah.php', fd, function(ajax){console.log(ajax.responseText)}, function(){} );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

### PHP

```
<?php
// blahBlah.php
    var_dump($_POST['whiteboardData']);

    $jsonObj = json_decode( $_POST['whiteboardData'] );

    $newObj = new wbData(200,300,200, [new vec2d(0,0), new vec2d(10,10), new vec2d(100,100)] );

    // append the new stuff
    $jsonObj[0]->whiteboardData[] = $newObj;

    var_dump( json_encode($jsonObj) );

//-----------------------------------
    class wbData
    {
        public function __construct ($r,$g,$b, $pts=[])
            {
                $this->color = [$r, $g, $b];
                //$this->pointList = [];
                $this->pointList = $pts;
            }
    };

    class vec2d
    {
        public function __construct($x=0, $y=0)
        {
            $this->x = $x;
            $this->y = $y;
        }
    }
?>
```

### RESULT IN CONSOLE

```
string(164) "[{"name":"example","id":"numbers","whiteboardData":[{"color":[100,150,100],"pointList":[{"x":100,"y":100}]}],"chatMessages":[{"sender":"username","content":"hi"}]}]"
string(250) "[{"name":"example","id":"numbers","whiteboardData":[{"color":[100,150,100],"pointList":[{"x":100,"y":100}]},{"color":[200,300,200],"pointList":[{"x":0,"y":0},{"x":10,"y":10},{"x":100,"y":100}]}],"chatMessages":[{"sender":"username","content":"hi"}]}]"
```

Comment: Okay thanks I modified that to work a bit better in my situation and it worked